# 正規表現を変更して求める出力を得たい

Tags: python3, 正規表現

#### 行いたいこと

ある単語（スペースや記号を含んで２単語以上もあり得る）が、対象文に含まれるかどうかを判定する

### 現在のコードと課題

現在のコードでは、対象文2、4のみ想定通りの出力となリます。

末尾にピリオドがあったり、前と後ろの両方にスペースがある場合は、どのように正規表現を定義するべきですか。

```py
import regex as re
words = ['are', 'John Smith', 'Mia & Tim']
re_words = "(" + "|".join(words) + "|" + ")"
target_1 = "I am John Smith."
target_2 = "Mia & Tim look fine"
target_3 = "There are Mia & Tim & Kate."
target_4 = "are you sure?"

print(re_words)
print(re.match(re_words, target_1)) #「John Smith」は含まれている
print(re.match(re_words, target_2))
print(re.match(re_words, target_3)) #「Mia & Tim」は含まれている
print(re.match(re_words, target_4))


#output
(are|John Smith|Mia & Tim|)
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 0), match=''>
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 9), match='Mia & Tim'>
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 0), match=''>
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 3), match='are'>
```

### 試したこと

`re.search`と以下のように変更してみましたが、結果に変更ありませんでした。

```py
import re
words = ['are', 'John Smith', 'Mia & Tim']
re_words = "(" + "|".join(words) + "|" + ")"
target_1 = "I am John Smith ."
target_2 = "Mia & Tim look fine"
target_3 = "There are Mia & Tim & Kate."
target_4 = "are you sure?"

print(re_words)
print(re.search(re_words, target_1))
print(re.search(re_words, target_2))
print(re.search(re_words, target_3))
print(re.search(re_words, target_4))


#output
(are|John Smith|Mia & Tim|)
<re.Match object; span=(0, 0), match=''>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 9), match='Mia & Tim'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 0), match=''>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 3), match='are'>
```

### 試したこと２

正規表現を修正したのですが、部分一致になると、以下の例でもマッチしてしまい、あくまでもスペース含む独立した単語でマッチしたいのでエラーケースを引き起こすことがわかりました。

```
import re
words = ['are', 'John Smith', 'Mia & Tim']
re_words = "(" + "| ".join(words) + ")"
target_4 = "areyou sure?"

print(re_words)
print(re.search(re_words, target_4))
```

Comment: `re_words = "(" + "|".join(words) + "|" + ")"` を `re_words = "(" + "|".join(words) + ")"` に変更して下さい。

Comment: 「スペース含む独立した単語」ということであれば、`re_words = rf"\b({'|'.join(words)})\b"`  を試してみて下さい。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/re.html#re.match)は**文字列の先頭が一致する**場合に値を返します。
部分一致で正規表現検索をかけたい場合は[`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/re.html#re.search)を使用してください。

参考資料:

- [search() vs. match()](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match)
- [【python】re.match より re.search を使おう](https://qiita.com/halhorn/items/9e6599a3422e7dd94ec8)

追記:
要望に合致するサンプルコードを作成しました。
連続する単語が前後にないことを確認する場合は、コメント回答にある`\b`(単語境界)を使用してください。

**サンプルコード**

```
import re
words = ['are', 'John Smith', 'Mia & Tim']

# 単語境界を使用する例
re_words = rf"\b({'|'.join(words)})\b"

# その他に、 \W(非単語文字)と ^(文頭)、 $(文末)を組み合わせて実現できなくもない
# re_words = r"(?:^|\W)(" + "|".join(words) + ")(?:\W|$)"

targets = {
    # "文章": "想定結果"
    "I am John Smith.": "John Smith",
    "I am John Smithhhhhhhhh.": None,
    "Mia & Tim look fine": "Mia & Tim",
    "There are Mia & Tim & Kate.": "are",
    "are you sure?": "are",
    "areyou sure?": None,
    "There are Mia & Tim & Kate.": "Mia & Tim", # 想定結果が間違っている例
}

print(re_words)

for target in targets.keys():
    wanted = targets[target]
    m = re.search(re_words, target)
    # 例文が想定結果になっているかチェックするアサーション(想定結果と異なる場合は例外となる)
    try:
        assert (wanted == None and m == None) or (wanted == m[1]), '文章: {0}, 想定結果: {1}", 実行結果: {2}'.format(target, wanted, m)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。「試したこと」に追記しましたが、正規表現定義側の問題のようで、出力で変化を確認できませんでした。

Comment: `re_words = "(" + "|".join(words) + "|" + ")"`を`re_words = "(" + "|".join(words) + ")"`に書き換えてください。末尾の`|`により、先頭のゼロ文字にヒットしてしまいます。(検証時に気付いていましたが、指摘漏れしていました)

Comment: ありがとうございます。正規表現を修正したのですが、部分一致になると、以下の例でもマッチしてしまい、あくまでもスペース含む独立した単語でマッチしたいのでエラーケースを引き起こすことがわかりました。